# Meaning of the word "check" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

It is from [Crash Course Navigating Digital Information](https://youtu.be/o93pM-b97HI). The piece is at 5 minute and 25 second.

> Hello, commentetors. It is me, John Green. I would like to thank you all 3.5 millions of you who have pointed out that the Nile river flows north in that Crash Course World History video. We know. That is why we published the correction in the annotations. We **check** us you didn't read.

I cannot really get what the presenter means by the last sentence. I even think I mesheard the piece, but I cannot tell as there are no subtitles. Rephrase the last sentence for me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misheard. He does not say "We check us you didn't read".

He actually says "*Which I guess you didn't read*".

The intended meaning is a sarcastic swipe at those who pointed out their error but did not read their correction.